# Gradient color in links of sankey chart using networkD3

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am using [networkD3](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#sankey) to create sankey diagrams in R. I am using something like below to generate the diagrams:

```
sankeyNetwork(Links = data$links, Nodes = data$nodes, 
          Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
          units = "Questions", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 10, 
          colourScale = "d3.scale.category10()",
          LinkGroup = "type",             #<--assign colors to links
          width = 1000, height = 600)
```

I am using `LinkGroup = "type"` to color the links, where the `type` is basically the source node's name. This makes the link color same as source node color. This is working pretty well.

I was wondering if there is anyway a gradient of color can be created from sources to targets for the associated links?